# Missing files or something in installing ROS. Lion

Tags: python, installation

I am trying to install the ROS complete desktop environment.... in mac osx lion. it is basically a problem on my mac...

```
Log for python26 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python26/python26/main.log
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: rosdep script failed with stderr 
{{{
Error: Target org.macports.destroot returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade python26 failed

}}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.22', 'rosinstall')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.22-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 679, in <module>

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.22-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 670, in rosinstall_main

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/rajeshmedampudi/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Please help or guide me in the right path... i am having a tough time to find any material.... thank you.....

adding the mac port installtion errors too....

```
:info:destroot 1 error generated.
:info:destroot make[2]: *** [MyAppDelegate.o] Error 1
:info:destroot make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python26/python26/work/Python-2.6.7/Mac/PythonLauncher'
:info:destroot make[1]: *** [install_PythonLauncher] Error 2
:info:destroot make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python26/python26/work/Python-2.6.7/Mac'
:info:destroot make: *** [frameworkinstallapps] Error 2
:info:destroot make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python26/python26/work/Python-2.6.7'
:info:destroot shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python26/python26/work/Python-2.6.7" && /usr/bin/make -w frameworkinstall maninstall MAKE="/usr/bin/make CC=/Developer/usr/bin/clang" DESTDIR=/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python26/python26/work/destroot " returned error 2
:error:destroot Target org.macports.destroot returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:destroot Backtrace: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"command_exec destroot"
    (procedure "portdestroot::destroot_main" line 2)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:destroot Warning: the following items did not execute (for python26): org.macports.activate org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:destroot Log for python26 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python26/python26/main.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MacPorts install is failing to upgrade python.

It is trying to upgrade python26, but is doing something from python27

Try

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install python26
```

and report back

Comment: i did install python as per what you have said and it worked... but i had to explictly work with easy_install-2.6 instead of easy_install. I had to completely reinstall the mac ports to make this happen... BY the way... Mercurial does need python27 is it...

Comment: I would now see which pythons you have installed. `sudo port select python` will show you a list of what you have installed and which is active. Mercurial might depend on python2.7, but whatever you are doing is invoking python2.6.   Does the file "/Users/rajeshmedampudi/ros/setup.sh" exist?

Comment: yes it does exist... and we need a 2.6 invoked... as all the files need to be 2.6 based... not 2.7

Comment: try `sudo port select python python26` then start a new terminal session, and try installing again

Comment: hmm.. it seems that i was having troubles with the setup environment ... seems to be altogether a different problem but hey... thank you for your efforts to help me in my endeavor for solving my issue.